# How to encrypt traffic between AWS EKS and external services?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, amazon-eks, servicemesh

How does EKS need to be configured to enable TLS/SSL between pods and external services such as RDS and MSK?

I could only find information on encrypting Kubernetes in-cluster traffic, but not for external traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All traffic exchanged between these Nitro instances is automatically encrypted with TLS, see [encryption in transit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/data-protection.html#encryption-transit). All AWS API service endpoints use TLS 1.2 (minimum), see [AWS cloud connections with TLS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/faster-aws-cloud-connections-with-tls-1-3/). For RDS, you will need to download the certificate bundle for the RDS database you're using, add it as a Kubernetes Secret, and reference that secret in your Pod. See this [post](https://paulbellamy.com/2017/07/connecting-to-postgres-rds-instances-from-ecs-with-ssl) for additional details. I'm less familiar with Kafka and TLS, but it seems doable. According to the documentation, you'll need to add a certificate to your client's trust store, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-authentication.html.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyCowan. What do you think about encrypting external pod traffic with other services outside of EKS using a service mesh?

Comment: You can do that so long as the "services outside of EKS" can participate in the mesh. You may be able to use VPC Lattice, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc-lattice/latest/ug/what-is-vpc-lattice.html, instead of running a mesh.